# Save Submitted Form Data to JSON File

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms

I was wondering what the best way is to go about saving submitted form data to a separate `data.json` file, so I can pull from it later.

I've got a very simple form that looks like this:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Service Name">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <label for="place">Place:</label>
        <select id="place">
          <option>The Whittington Hospital, London</option>
          <option>University College Hospital, London</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
    <button>Add Service</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I want to send the data that is submitted in that form, into a JSON file that looks like this:

```
 {
  "places":[
    {
      "name": "The Whittington Hospital",
      "address": {
        "city": "London",
      },

      "service": [{
        "type": [
          { "name": "Hernia Repair" },
          { "name": "Hip Replacement" },
          { "name": "Crohn's Disease", },
          { "name": "Pregnancy", }
        ]
      }]
      },
    {
      "name": "University College Hospital",
      "address": {
        "city": "London",
      },

      "service": [{
        "type": [
          {
            "name": "Hernia Repair" }
        ]
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is this an easy task to do? If so, how is best to go about achieving something like this?

I've setup a JSFiddle of the form here: http://jsfiddle.net/y6z74dkd/1/

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You need a serverside component if you want to save it on the server. If you want to save it to client's computer, you can do it by creating a download link with data-url.

Comment: @Amadan What sort of serverside component will I need? I'm learning a bit of AngularJS at the moment. Is there a server-side component that works well with this?

Comment: Any. PHP, Ruby on Rails, Sinatra, Node.js, CherryPy, Django, even bash CGI script if you're masochist enough, literally anything that can execute code on the server suffices.

Comment: Oh, third option: if you just need the data in your web-app for that user but don't need the user to have it, you can save it to local storage (but there will be no `data.json` file anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a web host that supports server-side code.

I recommend proceeding with php so here is some documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php